# Kendo Grid not binding to web service result

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I do not understand what is happening here, but I think it's just not understanding the schema properly. I've tried lots of different options, ways of expressing the schema, and I've tried different formats for the web service result, including XML, but I couldn't get any of it to work. I can verify (from Fiddler2) that the web service is being called and is returning data, and my grid is rendering the columns I said, but it won't show the data. I don't understand what I'm missing here, and whether I need to fix the web service result, or specify the schema differently, or something else?

My Javascript looks like this... (after trying lots of different stuff, this is currently what I have)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid" style="height: 400px; width: 900px;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myWebServiceUrl = 'wMDTData.asmx';

        var myGridData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: myWebServiceUrl + '/Read',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (response) { return response.d; },
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { type: "string" },
                        ITEM_NAME: { type: "string" },
                        FUNCTION_NM: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        myGridData.read();

        var myKendoGridOptions = {
            dataSource: {
                data: myGridData
            }, //end of dataSource: object
            columns: [{
                width: 90,
                field: "ID",
                title: "ID"
            }, {
                width: 90,
                field: "ITEM_NAME",
                title: "Item Name"
            }, {
                width: 100,
                field: "FUNCTION_NM",
                title: "Function Name"
            }]  //end of columns: array
        };

        $(document).ready(
            function () { $("#grid").kendoGrid(myKendoGridOptions); }
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I Fixed my Web Service response, it's a JSON string now, but things still aren't working. My web service responds with this...

```
{ "d":
    { "__type": "System.Data.DataTable", "columns": [
        { "name": "ID", "dataType": "Object", "defaultValue": null, "readOnly": false, "isKey": false },
        { "name": "ITEM_NAME", "dataType": "String", "defaultValue": null, "readOnly": false, "isKey": false },
        { "name": "FUNCTION_NM", "dataType": "String", "defaultValue": null, "readOnly": false, "isKey": false }
    ],
        "rows": [
            { "ID": 1, "ITEM_NAME": "VR data to Close Package", "FUNCTION_NM": "CLOSE_PACKAGE_MAP_TO_BC" },
            { "ID": 2, "ITEM_NAME": "Currency Conversion", "FUNCTION_NM": "WV_CURRENCY_CONVERSION" },
            { "ID": 3, "ITEM_NAME": "GL Coding (wMDT Mapping)", "FUNCTION_NM": "GL_MAPPING" }
        ]
    } 
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways to specify what elements to look at - XPath(string/), tried setting the ID column to "ID" - it just isn't parsing this. I can get it to return wicked ugly XML too, but the grid isn't playing nicely with this either...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DataTable>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
            <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Table" msprop:BaseTable.0="WMDT_ACCESS">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="ID" msprop:BaseColumn="ID" msprop:OraDbType="107" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="ITEM_NAME" msprop:BaseColumn="ITEM_NAME" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="FUNCTION_NM" msprop:BaseColumn="FUNCTION_NM" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
            <NewDataSet>
                <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                    <ID>1</ID>
                    <ITEM_NAME>VR data to Close Package</ITEM_NAME>
                    <FUNCTION_NM>CLOSE_PACKAGE_MAP_TO_BC</FUNCTION_NM>
                </Table>
                <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                    <ID>2</ID>
                    <ITEM_NAME>Currency Conversion</ITEM_NAME>
                    <FUNCTION_NM>WV_CURRENCY_CONVERSION</FUNCTION_NM>
                </Table>
                <Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
                    <ID>3</ID>
                    <ITEM_NAME>GL Coding (wMDT Mapping)</ITEM_NAME>
                    <FUNCTION_NM>GL_MAPPING</FUNCTION_NM>
                </Table>
            </NewDataSet>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
    </DataTable>
```

So, if there's a question here, it's which result should I use, and how to get that result to bind to the grid properly?

Sorry to post a "discussion" type question, but I'm being blocked from "normal" forums to ask this.

Comment: I did read this post: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/ 

However, when I add the content-type to my Jquery call, the web service returns an error.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery 1.9.0? Kendo UI is shipped with a version of Kendo UI that is 1.8.2 you might experience problems using 1.9.0. Could you try to reproduce it using _pre-packed_ jQuery?

Comment: Here is a sample showing how to bind to ASMX: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/grid-web-service-crud

Comment: Thanks, I've pulled all those samples already, this isn't my first time. Wrong JQuery version is something to look at though for sure.

Comment: Fixing the JQuery version didn't make this work. As far as I can see, it's the same as the examples, but it isn't rendering rows. It puts the grid there, with the right columns, but no rows ever show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only slightly different, but it works. Can someone explain why? I really don't like the "twiddle it until it works" cargo-cult programming method!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid" style="height: 400px; width: 900px;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myWebServiceUrl = 'wMDTData.asmx';

        var myGridData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: myWebServiceUrl + "/Read",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "d"
            }
        });

        myGridData.read();

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({ dataSource: myGridData });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Web service result is still the same as before, the JSON result. Can somebody explain what might be happening here? I'm going to put the "options" back in, and it seems like that's what was messing it up because it's the only thing I really removed.